# Pulseaudio problem: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I experience the following strange behavior of Pulseaudio:

- When I open and close Puvacontrol, sound is badly distorted.
- Usually sound works fine on boot. Sometimes it is also badly distorted. When I open Puvacontrol it works, and when I close Puvacontrol it is again badly distorted.

My distribution is Linux Mint 21, all packages up to date. The problem appeared recently, but I can't exactly pin down what exactly changed.

systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service gives the following:

```
> ● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-11-18 11:30:40 CET; 4min 42s ago 
>      TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket    
>      Main PID: 180724 (pulseaudio)
>      Tasks: 8 (limit: 18642)
>      Memory: 7.7M
>      CPU: 10.137s
>      CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
>              └─180724 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
> 
> Nov 18 11:30:40 XXX systemd[1129]: Starting Sound Service... 
> Nov 18 11:30:40 XXX pulseaudio[180724]: Stale PID file, overwriting. 
> Nov 18 11:30:40 XXX pulseaudio[180724]: Sink alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__source does not exist. 
> Nov 18 11:30:40 XXX systemd[1129]: Started Sound Service. 
> Nov 18 11:30:40 XXX pulseaudio[180724]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus-org.bluez.service not found. 
> Nov 18 11:31:04 XXX pulseaudio[180724]: ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was actually nothing to write. 
> Nov 18 11:31:04 XXX pulseaudio[180724]: Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp'. Please report this issue to the ALSA developers. 
> Nov 18 11:31:04 XXX pulseaudio[180724]: We were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail() returned 0 or another value < min_avail.
```

When I look at the output of pulseaudio -vvvv, when I close Puvacontrol it says:

```
> pulseaudio protocol-native.c connection died
```

I am very grateful for any suggestions how to fix this -- let me know if there are any logs / output I can provide to further pin down the issue.